# How to stream CSV from Flask via sqlalchemy query?

Tags: python, csv, flask

I'd like to stream a CSV from Flask using the technique [they describe here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/):

```
from flask import Response

@app.route('/large.csv')
def generate_large_csv():
    def generate():
        for row in iter_all_rows():
            yield ','.join(row) + '\n'
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```

I have a query from sqlalchemy that returns a list of Purchase objects. I'd like to write this to a CSV, ideally with customization over the attributes output to the file.

Unfortunately, I'm getting a blank CSV as output currently:

```
@app.route('/sales_export.csv')
@login_required
def sales_export():
    """ Export a CSV of all sales data """
    def generate():
        count = 0
        fieldnames = [
            'uuid',
            'recipient_name',
            'recipient_email',
            'shipping_street_address_1',
            'shipping_street_address_2',
            'shipping_city',
            'shipping_state',
            'shipping_zip',
            'purchaser_name',
            'purchaser_email',
            'personal_message',
            'sold_at'
        ]
        for i, row in enumerate(Purchase.query.all()):
            if i == 0:
                yield fieldnames
            csv = ','.join(row) + '\n'
            yield csv
    return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should determine where the problem originates from. It could be sqlalchmey not returning data, or flask not handling it correclty. 
Try printing the output of Purchase.query.all in console to check that sqlalchemy is doing what its supposed to

Comment: My query returns a list of objects as expected from the console.

Comment: Kinda, but not using the technique described in the question.

Comment: Just posted my solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I resolved this question. It doesn't use the streaming featured I was curious about originally. I would still be interested in a solution using that technique.

```
@app.route('/download')
@login_required
def download():
    "Export a CSV of all sales data"
    purchases = Purchase.query.all()
    csvfile = cStringIO.StringIO()
    headers = [
        'uuid',
        'recipient_name',
        'recipient_email',
        'shipping_street_address_1',
        'shipping_street_address_2',
        'shipping_city',
        'shipping_state',
        'shipping_zip',
        'purchaser_name',
        'purchaser_email',
        'personal_message',
        'sold_at',
        'coupon_used'
    ]
    rows = []
    for purchase in Purchase.query.all():
        rows.append(
            {
                'uuid': purchase.uuid,
                'recipient_name': purchase.recipient_name,
                'recipient_email': purchase.recipient_email,
                'shipping_street_address_1': purchase.shipping_street_address_1,
                'shipping_street_address_2': purchase.shipping_street_address_2,
                'shipping_city': purchase.shipping_city,
                'shipping_state': purchase.shipping_state,
                'shipping_zip': purchase.shipping_zip,
                'purchaser_name': purchase.purchaser_name,
                'purchaser_email': purchase.purchaser_email,
                'personal_message': purchase.personal_message,
                'sold_at': purchase.sold_at.strftime('%c'),
                'coupon_used': purchase.coupon_used
            }
        )
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(
            dict(
                (k, v.encode('utf-8') if type(v) is unicode else v) for k, v in row.iteritems()
            )
        )
    csvfile.seek(0)
    return send_file(csvfile, attachment_filename='sales_export.csv', as_attachment=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/#streaming-with-context

pretty much explains how to keep the context around

Answer (score 0):

Explain Ronny's answer: You should add `stream_with_context()` function to `Response()` for keeping the **Context**.